# How to bind to the Release of <Up> <Down> or other keyboard events in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Im able to bind to "Up" and "Down" events in Tkinter, but i can figure out how to bind to the release of these events?

Im doing something like:

```
Listbox.bind("<Up>", Update)
```

But this is giving me the listbox selection **before** the Up/Down key was pressed (as expected). Does anyone know how to bind to the release of a key press?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prefix key events with `KeyPress-` or `KeyRelease-`. For example `<KeyRelease-Up>`.

If you're trying to use this to get the selection, you are better off binding to `<<ListboxSelect>>` which always fires after the selection has changed.

Comment: `<<ListboxSelect>>` also has the advantage of working when you change the selection with the mouse, or when you change a multi-selection, etc.