# tkinter: multiple listbox does not fire up/down arrow keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to select items from the multilistbox in tkinter by binding events to the arrow keys.

The multilistbox works fine [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch09s05.html)! with mouse scrolling. But it doesn't work with the up/down arrow keys. I added the up/down arrow key binding to the code but it didn't fire when I hit on the arrow keys and neither of these solutions from [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29484287/tkinter-listbox-that-scrolls-with-arrow-keys)! and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261512/how-to-bind-to-the-release-of-up-down-or-other-keyboard-events-in-tkinter)! had worked for me.

Below is what I have added to the code in the link I provided:

```
...
lb.bind("<Down>", lambda e, s=self: s._OnEntryDown(e.y))
lb.bind("<Up>", lambda e, s=self: s._OnEntryUp(e.y))
...

...
def downarrow(self, *args):
   for l in self.lists:
       if self.selection < l.size()-1:
           l.select_clear(self.selection)
           self.selection += 1
           l.select_set(self.selection)


def uparrow(self, *args):
    for l in self.lists:
        if self.selection > 0:
            self.l.select_clear(self.selection)
            self.selection -= 1
            self.l.select_set(self.selection)
```

I am expecting selection by up/down arrow keys to work perfect as it does with a single listbox in tkinter. Please I need help!

Comment: Thanks for the reply and well noted! I was able to figure out my self and now I have it working. I will post the solution in the Answer entry.

Answer (score 0):

After making a several internet surfing, I was able to come across this  [link](https://github.com/achernet/pyscripts/blob/master/multilistbox.py)! on github but this was written in python 2.x so I modified it to work with python 3.x as well.
Below is the modified code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import copy
import csv
import logging
import os
import platform
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.constants as Tkc
import tkinter.filedialog as Tkfc
import tkinter.font as Tkf
import tkinter.messagebox as Tkmb
import webbrowser
import sys

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


class MultiListbox(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, lists):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.lists = []
        self.colmapping = {}
        self.orig_data = None
        self.fonts = {}
        self.y_sel = None
        for label, width in lists:
            frame = Frame(self)
            frame.pack(side=Tkc.LEFT, expand=Tkc.YES, fill=Tkc.BOTH)

            sort_button = Button(frame, text=label, borderwidth=1, relief=Tkc.RAISED)
            sort_button.pack(fill=Tkc.X)
            sort_button.bind("<Button-1>", self._sort)
            sort_button.config(font=self.header_font)

            self.colmapping[sort_button] = (len(self.lists), 1)
            list_box = Listbox(frame, width=width, borderwidth=0, selectborderwidth=0,
                              relief=Tkc.FLAT, exportselection=Tkc.FALSE)
            list_box.pack(expand=Tkc.YES, fill=Tkc.BOTH)
        self.lists.append(list_box)
            list_box.bind("<B1-Motion>", lambda e, s=self: s._select(e.y))
            list_box.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e, s=self: s._select(e.y))
            list_box.bind("<Leave>", lambda e: "break")
            list_box.bind("<B2-Motion>", lambda e, s=self: s._b2motion(e.x, e.y))
            list_box.bind("<Button-2>", lambda e, s=self: s._button2(e.x, e.y))
            list_box.bind("<Double-Button-1>", lambda e, s=self: s._activate(e.y))

        frame = Frame(self)
        frame.pack(side=Tkc.LEFT, fill=Tkc.Y)
        frame_label = Label(frame, borderwidth=1, relief=Tkc.RAISED)
        frame_label.pack(fill=Tkc.X)
        scroll_bar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=Tkc.VERTICAL, command=self._scroll)
        scroll_bar.pack(expand=Tkc.YES, fill=Tkc.Y)
        self.lists[0]["yscrollcommand"] = scroll_bar.set

        # Configure scrolling by arrow keys and Page Up/Down.
        self.bind_all("<Up>", lambda e, s=self: s._scroll("scroll", "-1", "units", select=True))
        self.bind_all("<Down>", lambda e, s=self: s._scroll("scroll", "1", "units", select=True))
        self.bind_all("<Next>", lambda e, s=self: s._scroll("scroll", "1", "pages", select=True))
        self.bind_all("<Prior>", lambda e, s=self: s._scroll("scroll", "-1", "pages", select=True))
        self.bind_all("<Return>", lambda e, s=self: s._activate(e.y))

       self.master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.master.destroy)

    @property
    def header_font(self):
        if "header" in self.fonts:
            return self.fonts["header"]
        font_families = sorted(Tkf.families(self.master))
        if "Liberation Sans" in font_families:
            family = "Liberation Sans"
        else:
            family = "Tahoma"
        font = Tkf.Font(family=family, size=13, weight=Tkf.BOLD)
        self.fonts["header"] = font
        return font

    def _sort(self, event):

        # Get the listbox to sort by (mapped by the header buttons)
        originating_button = event.widget
        column, direction = self.colmapping[originating_button]

        # Make an in-memory copy of all the table data.
        table_data = self.get(0, Tkc.END)
        if self.orig_data is None:
            self.orig_data = copy.deepcopy(table_data)
        row_count = len(table_data)

        # Remove any old sort indicators (if they exist)
        for button in self.colmapping:
            button_text = button.cget("text")
            if button_text[0] == "[":
                button.config(text=button_text[4:])

        # Sort data based on direction.
        button_label = originating_button.cget("text")
        if direction == 0:
            table_data = self.orig_data
        elif direction == 1:
            originating_button.config(text="[+] {0}".format(button_label))
            table_data.sort(key=lambda obj: obj[column], reverse=False)
        else:  # direction == -1
            originating_button.config(text="[-] {0}".format(button_label))
            table_data.sort(key=lambda obj: obj[column], reverse=True)

        # Clear and refill the widget.
        self.delete(0, Tkc.END)
        for row in range(row_count):
            self.insert(Tkc.END, table_data[row])

        # Finally, toggle the direction flag.
        if direction == 1:
            direction = -1
        else:
            direction += 1
        self.colmapping[originating_button] = column, direction

    def _activate(self, y):
        item_info = self.get(self.curselection()[0])
        logging.info("Opening PyPI web page for item: %s", item_info)
        pypi_url = "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/{0[0]}".format(item_info)
        webbrowser.open_new(pypi_url)

    def _select(self, y):
        row = self.lists[0].nearest(y)
        logging.info("Selecting Y point %s (got row %s)", y, row)
        return self._select_row(row)

    def _select_row(self, row):
        logging.info("Selecting row %d", row)
        self.selection_clear(0, Tkc.END)
        self.selection_set(row)
        # self.see(row)
        return "break"

    def _button2(self, x, y):
        logging.info("Button 2 at (%d, %d)", x, y)
        for list_widget in self.lists:
            list_widget.scan_mark(x, y)
        return "break"

    def _b2motion(self, x, y):
        logging.info("B2 Motion to (%d, %d)", x, y)
        for list_widget in self.lists:
            list_widget.scan_dragto(x, y)
        return "break"

    def _scroll(self, *args, select=False):
        #select = kwargs.pop("select", False)
        logging.info("Scrolling -- args: %s, select: %s", args, select)

        if select and self.curselection():
            new_index, should_do_scroll = self.get_new_selection(args)
            if new_index is None:
                logging.debug("No selection change for args: %s - scrolling...", args)
                should_do_scroll = True
            else:
                old_index = int(self.curselection()[0])
                logging.debug("Changing selection from index %d to %d", old_index, new_index)
                self._select_row(new_index)
        else:
            should_do_scroll = True

        if should_do_scroll:
            for list_widget in self.lists:
                list_widget.yview(*args)

    def get_new_selection(self, scroll_args):
        """
    If selection change upon scrolling is enabled, return the new index that should be selected after the
    scroll operation finishes. If the new index is currently visible, just select it and skip the actual
    scrolling process entirely.

    :param list scroll_args: The arguments passed to the scrollbar widget
    :return tuple: The index that should be selected afterward, followed by its current "selectability"
    """
        cur_selection = self.curselection()

        # If the scrollbar is being dragged, or if nothing is currently selected, then do not select anything.
        if scroll_args[0] != "scroll" or not cur_selection:
            return None, False
        amount = int(scroll_args[1])
        pixel_dict = self.get_pixel_dict()
        page_size = len(pixel_dict) - 2 if scroll_args[2] == "pages" else 1
        scroll_diff = amount * page_size
        old_index = int(cur_selection[0])
        new_index = max(0, min(self.lists[0].size() - 1, old_index + scroll_diff))
        return new_index, new_index not in pixel_dict

    def curselection(self):
        return self.lists[0].curselection()

    def delete(self, first, last=None):
        for list_widget in self.lists:
            list_widget.delete(first, last)

    def get(self, first, last=None):
        result = []
        for list_widget in self.lists:
            result.append(list_widget.get(first, last))
        if last:
            return map(*[None] + result)
        return result

    def index(self, index):
        self.lists[0].index(index)

    def insert(self, index, *elements):
        for elem in elements:
            i = 0
            for list_widget in self.lists:
                list_widget.insert(index, elem[i])
                i += 1

    def size(self):
        return self.lists[0].size()

    def see(self, index):
        for list_widget in self.lists:
            list_widget.see(index)

    def selection_anchor(self, index):
        for list_widget in self.lists:
            list_widget.selection_anchor(index)

    def selection_clear(self, first, last=None):
        for list_widget in self.lists:
            list_widget.selection_clear(first, last)

    def selection_includes(self, index):
        return self.lists[0].selection_includes(index)

    def selection_set(self, first, last=None):
        for list_widget in self.lists:
           list_widget.selection_set(first, last)

    def get_pixel_dict(self):
        list_box = self.lists[0]
        height = list_box.winfo_height() + 1
        pixel_dict = {list_box.nearest(height): height}
        for pixel in range(height, 0, -1):
            pixel_dict[list_box.nearest(pixel)] = pixel
        max_index, bottom_y = max(pixel_dict.items())
        item_height = bottom_y - pixel_dict.get(max_index - 1, 1)
        while bottom_y + item_height < height:
            max_index += 1
            bottom_y += item_height
            pixel_dict[max_index] = bottom_y
        pixel_dict.pop(max_index)
        return pixel_dict


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tk = Tk()
    Label(tk, text='MultiListbox').pack(side=TOP)
    mlb = MultiListbox(tk, (('Subject', 40), ('Sender', 20), ('Date', 10)))

    for i in range(5000):
        mlb.insert(END, ('Important Message: %d' % i, 'John Doe %d' % i, '10/10/%04d' % (1900+i)))
        mlb.pack(expand=YES,fill=BOTH,side=TOP)
    mlb.selection_set(0)
    tk.mainloop()
```